# Yocto - exclude files from -dev package

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have a great problem moving some header files from `FILES_${PN}-dev` to a custom dev-internal package.

In OpenEmbedded documentation there is explicitly stated that there is "no actual support for explicitly excluding files from packaging".

I tried this:

```
FILES_${PN}-dev = ""
PACKAGES += "${PN}-dev-internal"
FILES_${PN}-dev-internal = "${includedir}/<my-pattern>.h"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "<original-content>"
```

but it seems that the first defined package captures first anyway.

Is there any known workaround for this? Except of naming everything explicitly in both packages content which is highly, really undesirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but it seems that the first defined package captures first anyway.

Yes.  So put `PN-dev-internal` before `PN-dev` in `PACKAGES`. This might work:

```
PACKAGES =+ "${PN}-dev-internal"
```

If not, `PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN` is useful.

Comment: Thank you, the prepend operator works! Btw. what is then a difference between the 2 solutions? It's not clear to me from a Yocto documentation.

Comment: @blizzard PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN will insert the new package right before $(PN} but after all other packages. And it only works if PACKAGES are not declared explicitly like this PACKAGES = "${PN} ..."

Answer (score 0):

You can probably change the component installation config to better separate the headers (e.g. place them in different directories).

Comment: Sorry but this is clear antisolution... See above how an answer should look like.